Search box operators
Is there a way to find which operators a site’s search box admits?
For example, in BlueSky I wanted to find all posts in a certain language, looking for a user who suggested using the lang:it operator.

Going to depend entirely on the site, but for Bluesky it is lang.
Usually it will be documented, or findable via an advanced search page. Bluesky ones can be found here:
https://bsky.social/about/blog/05-31-2024-search
